# Domain abstraction and Hibernate reality

Tags: hibernate, oop, domain-driven-design

I'm about to start my first DDD project and I wonder to what extent Hibernate can handle polymorphism and what the consequences are.

I have noticed that they don't use abstraction at all [here](http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/) to express the domain even though their flag statement is something like "free the domain", "make real OO design" and so on. Is this because they wanted an example to be really simple or they cannot do that from some reason?

I know that Hibernate reposiories cannot be used at interface level. They can be used at abstract class level I believe, right? But what about such scenario:

There is a domain object **A** which contains abstract domain object (can't be interface :() **B**. There are several implementations of **B**. There is something like "**addSomeB**" method in **A**. I want to put there intermixed subclasses of **B**. Then am I able to store such class and retrieve it correctly?

Maybe there are some obvious scenerios where OO design isn't simply possible because of Hibernate limitations?

Thanks!

Comment: Hibernate supports inheritance with several [solutions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html), can you give some code example?

Comment: Not really. It was rather a conceptual problem - the matter of can or can't.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate supports inheritance, see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html

Contrary to you I've to mark inheritance as one of great feature within the framework. We successfully persisted one aggregate which has one base class (actually interface) and probably ten different implementations within spread inheritance tree.

> I know that Hibernate repositories cannot be used at interface level. They can be used at abstract class level I believe, right? But what about such scenario:

You can definitely use interfaces in your domain model. We did it. We had one jar with interfaces, and more jars with implementations.

Obviously as interface has no real values/content but entity itself (implementation) does (as it holds the content), you need to map implementations within you mappings - it works fine. You can still use interfaces within your services, even within you repositories - just use them in method signature.